# Why is on a occasion, only part of a record inserted?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

The problem I am having is on occasion (1 of every 8 or so) insertions to the database, the string value of (fileLocation) will be incomplete. so for example..

what should be "filecomplete.mp4" will be inserted as "filecomple".

Has anyone experienced this before or have any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Here is my insert statement.

```
public function addNewGame($gameID, $receiverID, $senderID, $gameTrack, $fileLocation){

        $this->gameid = $gameID;
        $this->receiverid = $receiverID;
        $this->senderid = $senderID;
        $this->gameTrack = $gameTrack;
        $this->filelocation = $fileLocation;

        $SQUERY = "SELECT GameId FROM ActiveGames WHERE GameId = :gameid";

        try{

            $stamt = $this->connection->prepare($SQUERY);

            if ($stamt === false) {
                throw new Exception($this->connection->error);
            }

            $stamt->bindValue(':gameid', $this->gameid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stamt->execute();

            $result = $stamt->fetchAll();
            $resultCount = count($result);

            if($resultCount > 0){

                echo "existing record";

            } else{

                $QUERY = "INSERT INTO ActiveGames (GameId,
                  ReceiverId,
                  SenderId,
                  GameTrack,
                  FileLocation)

                  VALUES (

                  :gameid,
                  :receiverid,
                  :senderid,
                  :gametrack,
                  :filelocation)";

                try{

                    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($QUERY);

                    if ($stmt === false) {
                        throw new Exception($this->connection->error);
                    }

                    $stmt->bindValue(':gameid', $this->gameid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':receiverid', $this->receiverid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':senderid', $this->senderid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':gametrack', $this->gameTrack, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':filelocation', $this->filelocation, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $stmt->execute();

                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {

                    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                    die();
                }

            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){

            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of the `FileLocation` column?

Comment: its VARCHAR with a max length of 128, I just noticed ive set the MIME type to plain/text as it receives a string value from JSON formatted in UTF-8.

Comment: I have removed the MIME/Type and it appears to be inserting correctly, I am a bit confused as to why it would only allow some of the characters to be inserted however. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.